# Tidy with PHP - output <link>, <style> and <script> elements without explicit type?

Tags: php, tidy

I'm testing Tidy with PHP to add a 'human' layout view of a given HTML page once it's sent to the browser (it's generated in compressed form by default), but I have a problem.

Every `<link>` element with its `rel` attribute set to **stylesheet** gets `type="text/css"` appended at its end. Same goes for the `<style>` element, which behaves in the same fashion. The `<script>` element gets `type="text/javascript"` appended.

While it's perfectly fine for me, I would like to filter these bits out, and I would like to know if there's an option in the Tidy configuration (I've been reading the option list [in the Tidy website](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html) but haven't found anything suggesting me such filtering) or I must do the filtering manually with something like:

```
$output = str_replace([" type=\"text/javascript\"", " type=\"text/css\""], ["", ""], tidy_parse_string($input, $options, "utf8"));
```

Is there a better filtering procedure than this one?

Comment: And why wouldn't you want them there, I always add them even when manually writing HTML myself, even if they aren't strictly required in HTML5

Comment: As I said, it's perfectly fine for me to have them, but I'm curious to know if I can get rid on them (in case I want). Not really a priority and even less of a need (I always send my HTML output in compressed form)

Comment: There's probably a way to ignore certain errors, like missing type attributes, but I have no idea how ?